# Съезжает лого вверх

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте, есть проблема в navbar boostrap.

Дело в том, что используя комбинацию лого+текст при некоторых разрешениях, например 780х1080 лого сползает вверх, но на других(большие(ПК/лаптоп) и маленьких(телефон) всё в норме:

[image: Съезд]

При этом без текста всё в норме:
[image: Норма]

Как урегулировать текст, чтобы не спозало лого вверх?
Код: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awbXmr

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="http://central.devlea.ru/logo.png" class="logo" style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 4px; display: inline-block;">
                <span class="site-name">
                    GO SAKU TENSHI
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    width: auto;
}

.site-name{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #401640;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Может `float: left;` для картинки и текста подойдёт?

Comment: @Cactus, увы, не сработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте вашему `navbar`

```
position:relative;
```

Поместите в отдельнный блок логотип и название.

Блоку с логотипом и названием задайте

```
position:absolute;
```

Если не получилось скинте код меню с `HOME` и.т.д

Comment: Сработало, правда текст налез на лого: http://savepic.org/8642486.png

Comment: Поместите в отдельнный блок логотип и название.

Блоку с логотипом и названием задайте

`position:absolute;`

Comment: Поместил: http://savepic.org/8620982.png. Верно всё сделал, или ошибся? Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: не задвйте для логотипа и названия `position:absolute;` а только для `navbar-brand`

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, помогло. Правда, только прописывание position: absolute; для navbar-brand, ибо если relative задать navbar появляетс белая плашка. А так -- всё отлично работает, хорошего Вам дня! :)

Comment: Попробуйте задать navbar `position:fixed;`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59865/discussion-between-duoxx-and-felix).